# How can I make mirror images of digit camera image files?

Tags: projection, eyepiece

My problem is that I am using a SONY a6000 mirrorless ILC and eyepiece projection to take images of solar system objects using a Schmidt Cassegrain Telescope. (SCT).

Prime focus photography with an SCT, or any other telescope produces images that are "normal", the sensor to digital image accounts for the inversion effects of focusing. With eyepiece projection there is a are two focusing steps, once by the telescope, at prime focus, and once by the eyepiece. The effect is a mirror image. Is there any setting on the camera or a piece of shareware that corrects for the mirror image effect. With a film camera, all I would have to do is flip the negative.

Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: The effect isn't a mirror image by replacing the eyepiece with a camera; it's a 180° _rotation_ of the image. A flipped mirror image (either vertically or horizontally) cannot be achieved by refractive optics — it requires a mirror to make a single-axis inversion (mirror image).

Answer (score 5):

Sure. Just about any editing software can do this. If you are producing JPEG images, one easy way is to use [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/), which has an option to mirror either horizontally or vertically, and will do this without any reduction in image quality. (If you open a JPEG image in a photo editor and flip it and resave as JPEG, you will probably get recompression artifacts. But jpegtran will avoid this.)

There are many, many other pieces of software that do this, but watch for the "lossless" gotcha. Or, if you are using RAW, you don't have this worry; just flip the image as part of RAW conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to have exactly the same effect as flipping the negative, then:

```
nconvert -jpegtrans hflip <filename>
```

...will do it for you *losslessly*. Run in a `foreach` to transform all files. Here is the [page for nconvert](https://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/). It is a very efficient and capable software, I use it almost daily.

Just like with a film camera, you will still be framing upside down. If you want to fix the preview, then I do not know of any camera that has this feature nor how to hack it into doing so but you can always flip an external monitor connected to via the HDMI port. There are tons of *On-Camera Monitor* to do that, just search for that term.

Answer (score 0):

Two packages that are free and general purpose.

- For RAW or JPEG files use RawTherapee (a very powerful RAW developer) and locate the "flip horizontally" icon and tap it.  There's also a "flip vertically".
- For JPEG files use GIMP and go to the menu and select "Image->Transform->Flip Horizontally" (or flip vertically).

Both of these will also do rotations.

If you do astrophotography then RAW files is the way I'd suggest and note that RawTherapee also supports Hot pixel removal (be default and can be turned off) and Dead pixel correction (off by default) as well as Dark Frame correction.

RawTherapee also does batch file processing.